# Linking Error - Use nm to fix

Tags: c, unix, gcc, linker, nm

I have a linking error which I'm supposed to fix using the `nm` command on Unix.

If I have the following linking error: `undefined reference to 'program_name'`, and when running `nm` on that object file, `program_name` symbol is shown as follows in the symbol table: `U program_name`.

I know `program_name` is undefined, and is defined in another object file which needs to be included with the original object file. My question is: how can I find which object file it is? Is that possible? I have a bunch of object files in a directory and it would be one of them. There's way too many to try all of them.

Comment: You could also make all your object files into an archive library and link against that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$ nm *.o
```

Look for `program_name` in the output (assuming you have a `.o` extension on your object files).

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Instead of a `U` in the output, you'll find a `T` (for "text segment") in the object file that has the symbol defined.  Something like this should work (in bash):

```
for f in *.o; do if (nm "$f" | grep 'T program_name'); then echo "$f" matches; fi; done
```

Here, I'm looping over all *.o files, and whichever ones have the symbol defined get their filenames printed out.

Answer (score 0):

Try `nm -o *.o |grep program_name` and look for the .o file where the symbol has a type of "T" (assuming it's a function name).  the `-o` option to nm prefixes each line with the filename.  Depending on your os, nm may or may not have this option (it might also be `-A`) so check your manpages.  If it's not there at all, then you'll need to write a shell for loop, something like

```
for obj in *.obj; do 
  echo $obj:
  nm $obj | grep program_name
done`
```